# How to click the element using automation id in Xamarin.UiTest?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, automation, xamarin.uitest

The app is developed using Xamarin.forms. I am examining the app using repl(). While using tree command i can see following output

```
>>> tree
[[object CalabashRootView] > DecorView]
  [LinearLayout > FrameLayout]
    [FitWindowsFrameLayout] id: "action_bar_root"
      [ContentFrameLayout > ... > PlatformRenderer] id: "content"
        [NavigationPageRenderer] id: "NoResourceEntry-9"
          [PageContainer] id: "NoResourceEntry-22"
            [PageRenderer > Platform_DefaultRenderer] id: "NoResourceEntry-17"
              [Platform_DefaultRenderer] label: "TermsAndConditions_main"
                [Platform_DefaultRenderer]
                  [Platform_DefaultRenderer]
                    [BoxRenderer] label: "TermsAndConditions_boxview"
                    [ExtendedLabelRenderer] label: "TermsAndConditions_lbTitle_Container"
                      [FormsTextView] id: "NoResourceEntry-18",  label: "TermsAndConditions_lbTitle",  text: "TERMS & CONDITIONS"
                    [BoxRenderer] label: "TermsAndConditions_boxview1"
                  [WebViewRenderer] label: "TermsAndConditions_webViewText_Container"
                    [WebView] id: "NoResourceEntry-19",  label: "TermsAndConditions_webViewText"
                [Platform_DefaultRenderer] label: "TermsAndConditions_btn"
                  [FrameRenderer > LabelRenderer] id: "NoResourceEntry-20"
                    [FormsTextView] id: "NoResourceEntry-21" text: "Accept"
  [View] id: "statusBarBackground"
```

All the automation Id is represented in the tree by `label` tag. How can i interact with the element with the `label` tag?

For example, i want to click the element with label `TermsAndConditions_btn`. How can i do this in Xamarin Uitest??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the label with something like `static readonly Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> MyLabel = c => c.Marked("TermsAndConditions_btn");` and then call `app.Tap(MyLabel)`.

Comment: thanks!! it worked. i am able to tap element using **Marked**. I can do it as **app.Tap(x => x.Marked("TermsAndConditions_btn"))**